# filtered data over functions

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I use a dataset (lst) obtained from a mysql table.

based on a datrangeinput I apply a filter

```
dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date Range", start = min(lst$Record_Date), end = max(lst$Record_Date))


observeEvent(input$daterange, {
  st <- input$daterange[1]
  ed <- input$daterange[2]

  lst  <- lst %>%
    filter(Record_Date >= st &
           Record_Date <= ed)

})
```

when I use the filtered "lst" in an other function the "lst" appears to be unfiltered again.

should I subset the filtered data in a new dataframe instead?

I was actually trying to avoid that to reduce memory use.

Thx

Comment: use reactive values rather than observeEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested to take a closer look into scoping rules and environments for shiny apps.

When you write "another function", you probably mean also outside that `observeEvent()` function. Then, it is another environment and you will have to pass the data to the other environment.

**Your example:**

```
 # inital data
 lst <- ...

filteredLst <- reactive(
  input$daterange
  isolate({
    st <- input$daterange[1]
    ed <- input$daterange[2]

    lst  <- lst %>%
      filter(Record_Date >= st &
            Record_Date <= ed)
    lst
  })
})

observe({
  lst # old data
  lst <- filteredLst() # filtered data in new environment
})
```

**Details about passing data between environments and reactivity:**

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

**Details about scoping:**

*"Where you define objects will determine where the objects are visible."*

A detailed explanation can be find here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html.

Comment: with regards to scoping, I have a large mysql table which I load in global.R.
I understand this dataset is then available for all sessions.
The mysql table is refreshed hourly.
Is there a way I can refresh the table in global.R on an hourly basis, making the updated dataset available in server.R?

Comment: sry didnt see the comment. You could use https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/invalidateLater.html. e.g. `invalidateLater(3600*1000)`. An upvote would be appreciated, thanks.